# Can I open webview link in browser without change java code?

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, android-webview

In my webview app, some external url will open in same webview, I want these link open in default browser.

I know I can use shouldOverrideUrlLoading to solve this problem, but I don't want change java code because some reason.

Is it possible solve this in HTML or Javascript?

Some people said, I can use this

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[target="_blank"]', function(ev) {
    var url;
    ev.preventDefault();
    url = $(this).attr('href');
    window.open(url, '_system');
});
```

But I tried, it does not work.

Comment: Um so the difference is you are setting a different window name? Why not set the link target to "_system"?

Answer (score 1):

When you say it doesn't work, is it because of `window.open()` failed to load it into a new window, or the click handler didn't get triggered at all?

- `window.open(url, '_system')` will open the url into the *same* window every time.
- Try `window.open(url, '_blank')` to launch a new tab/window every time.

But first of all, make sure your click handler is triggered.

Comment: I can sure the function is triggered, because I tested.